# Why doesn't Wireless Network Connection box show up?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I'm running Win7; when I click on the Wi-Fi button in the tray, the box won't pop up. Right-clickng does bring up troubleshoot and open network.

Comment: umm, I have a working wifi connection and on windows 7 when I right click the tray icon I see open network and sharing and troubleshooting this is normal behavior. What happens when you left click it does it bring up available networks?

Comment: that's the problem, left-clicking doesn't show anything (right works fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and... What does troubleshoot say?

Most common problems -

1) Make sure your wireless is turned on (Hardware switch or <kbd>FN</kbd>+an <kbd>F-Key</kbd>.

2) Go to `Network Connections` and make sure your wireless card is not disabled.

3) Go to `Device Manager` and make sure it is not disabled.

Those are the most common problems to deal with your symptoms, if it doesn't help, I really need more information.

Comment: Nothing is disabled, and the troublshooter detect nothing. I've tried updating and rolling back the drivers, diabling/reenabling the device, and turning the wifi an/off. Sometimes the dialog DOES op up when I click the wifi icon, but its very rare.

Comment: even disabled, the dialog should come up.... are you waiting/giving it enough time? :S

Comment: I waited about 4-5 mins just to be sure.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

Easier than you think...

In Vista you **right-click** on the network icon to get the list of available wireless networks.

In Win7 you **left-click** on the network icon to get the same list

In Win7 if you **right-click** you only see

```
                  Troubleshoot Problems
                  Open Network and Sharing Center
```

Then in Win7 you have to 'Open Network and Sharing Center' and click on

```
    View your active networks........................ **Connect or disconnect**
```

clicking on **Connect or disconnect** will bring up the available wireless networks list

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that worked for me:

1. Run Task Manager (easiest is "Ctrl+Shift+Esc")
2. Right click "explorer.exe"
3. Click "restart" (or "End task" and next "File">"New Task" and type in "explorer.exe")

The window showed up when I left clicked the icon.

Comment: This fixed it for me on windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Try terminating and restarting the "Network List Service":

1. Open the command prompt with Administrative privileges (if you press Ctrl-Shift-Esc and go to File -> Run, you can start "cmd" with Administrative privileges)
2. Type `sc queryex netprofm | find "PID"`
3. Note the PID that is returned.
4. Type `taskkill /F /PID **PID_YOU_WROTE_DOWN_EARLIER_HERE**` (without the asterisks)... e.g.: `taskkill /F /PID 872`
5. Type `net start netprofm`

Comment: Or, more simply, replace step 2 - 4 with `net stop netprofm`

Answer (score 0):

1. Try rebooting.
2. Try to install the latest stable network drivers.
3. Try to do a rollback using [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/system-restore).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what causes this, and how to fix it. See:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/13102-notification-area-icons-reset.html

It turns out the network list stops appearing because Windows gets "confused" about what object it's supposed to show in its Notification Area. The page above includes a batchfile you can run to (harmlessly) remove missing/obsolete entries from the Notification Area. Then, when you restart Windows, the network list should appear when you click the network icon. It worked for me!